# Factory class is not supporting SOLID principle

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, solid-principles

I have code as shown below

```
 public interface ICar
{
    void Created();
}

public class BigCar : ICar
{
    public void Created()
    {

    }
}

public class SmallCar : ICar
{
    public void Created()
    {

    }
}


public class LuxaryCar : ICar
{
    public void Created()
    {

    }
}

public class CarFactory
{
    public ICar CreateCar(int carType)
    {
        switch (carType)
        {
            case 0:
                return new BigCar();
            case 1:
                return new SmallCar();
            case 2:
                return new LuxaryCar();
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In this code I have a factory which is returning the concrete instances. But every time I need to have a new implementation of the ICar interface, I have to change the CreateCar() method of the  CarFactory. It seems like I am not supporting the Open Closed Principle of the SOLID principles. Please suggest is there a better way to handle this scenario.

Comment: You shouldn't pass `carType` to `CreateCar` method. Instead factory itself will decide what car type it creates. And you will create different factories for each car type you want to support.

Comment: @Vlad That means the switch statement will move to some place where you decide which factory to use. IMHO, the OP is asking how to eliminate the switch statement altogether. Even if you create the factory at the call-site, you need to convert the `carType` to a factory somehow.

Comment: You should use some config-file that contains the type-names and assemblies were to look for the types to be created associated with a key. Then you can use `Activator.CreateInstance` for that type within your factory.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, that won't help because for every new `ICar` there has to be a new key and for every new key there has to be a new `case` in the factory. You're back at square one.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Not quite. You won´t need any switch in this case, all you´re doing is calling `Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(typeFromConfig))`, maybe you have to add the assemblies into the load-context but this is everything. No use for `switch`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, yeah that makes more sense. No key at all, just read the type from a config file. I was about to write an answer suggesting that.

Comment: `public interface ICarFactory { ICar CreateCar(); }` and then `public class BigCarFactory : ICarFactory { ICar CreateCar() { return new BigCar(); } }`, and repeat for other types?

Comment: @ray, this is what Vlad suggested in the first comment

Comment: @slawekwin, Seems like it, but I thought it verbose and not entirely unambiguous for OP. I would've liked OP to explain why this is not what he/she has done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to make it configurable, like this:

```
void Main()
{
    // configurable array
    var factories = new ICarFactory[] { new BigCarFactory() };

    // create factory
    var realfactory = new CarFactory(factories);

    // create car
    var car = realfactory.CreateCar(0);
}

public class CarFactory : ICarFactory
{
    private ICarFactory[] _factories;

    public CarFactory (ICarFactory[] factories)
    {
        _factories = factories;

    }   
    public ICar CreateCar(int carType)
    {
        return _factories.Where(x=>x.SupportCar(carType)).First().CreateCar(carType);
    }

    public bool SupportCar(int type) => _factories.Any(x=>x.SupportCar(type));
}

public interface ICarFactory
{
    ICar CreateCar(int type);
    bool SupportCar(int type);
}

public class BigCarFactory : ICarFactory
{
    public ICar CreateCar(int carType)
    {
        if(carType != 0) throw new NotSupportedException();
        return new BigCar();
    }

    public bool SupportCar(int type) => type == 0;
}


public interface ICar
{
    void Created();
}

public class BigCar : ICar
{
    public void Created()
    {

    }
}

public class SmallCar : ICar
{
    public void Created()
    {

    }
}


public class LuxaryCar : ICar
{
    public void Created()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for solving my problem. It helped a lot.

Comment: @Vikram, I don't understand how this solved anything. The `switch` statement is now just scattered all over the place, i.e. it involves the array `ICarFactory[] factories`, the Linq filter `Where()` and lots of `SupportCar(int)` implementations. The problem has just been moved to a different place (multiple places in fact).

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Yes I agree that code is scattered at many places. There are lots of classes. But all the concerns are separated. All the classes are doing exactly what they are supposed to do. There is no class here which I have to change time again and again.

Comment: @Vikram, except that there is one. You have to update the `factories` array for every new car type. So where is the difference to updating the `switch` statement?

Comment: @Vikram, I have to agree with GoodNightNerdPride, this answer does not really solve anything and has issues following "SOLID" principles like you had asked. I think [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39489569/4594973), based on Vlad's original comment, better addresses the underlying issue.

Comment: The `ICarFactory[]` is a part of the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) which is often expected to change. This design is a variation of the tester-doer pattern and is a great approach for creating an extensible abstraction. [Here's another useful link](http://softwareonastring.com/619/designing-your-way-out-of-the-canhandle-handle-conundrum) worth considering for this design.

Answer (score 4):

There is a lot of [confusion around the open/closed principle, and what it should mean to your code](http://codeofrob.com/entries/my-relationship-with-solid---the-big-o.html).

The fact is here, you're fine. Moving to a config file just divides the code from the data and hides the intent, which will lead to problems.

The answer? It depends. Be pragmatic. "Just f**king hardcode it". Make the intent of the factory clear by keeping your switch statement. Keep the data and the intent close together, as here. Make sure you start by writing a test for missing `switch` cases and always include a `default` case (even if it just throws an exception).

Your factory only has one reason to change, and only does one job. Your design as you have it is just fine for now. If you find you are regularly coming back, adding new cases, then perhaps you'll want to think about some other way around it (a config file is not the answer, it's just moving the editing to a config file from a code file) and refactor your solution. Ever-increasing switch statements are not good, but rather than figuring out how to do that a different way, spend effort trying to remove that problem in the first place. See addendum below:

### Addendum

Another way out of this is to not have multiple classes implementing the same interface. Think about the other SOLID principles. Perhaps there is another consistency or functional boundary rather than "types of car"? Perhaps there are groups of functionality that could be specified in more, specific, fine-grained interfaces, and then maybe you use DI to have the implementations injected where you need them, rather than having to use a factory in the first place (which, let's face it, is just a trumped-up constructor anyway). See also: "favouring composition over inheritance".

Comment: Programmers sometimes forget that design patterns, paradigms and principles are no hard science. Very often it's a trade-off and the trick is to use the pattern that suits *your* domain best. [A discussion of the same question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/302780/does-the-factory-pattern-violate-the-open-closed-principle) on another stackexchange site came to similar conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my comments are misunderstood, so here we go:

Assume we have some easy config-file:

```
<config>
  <MyType key="1" type="My.Namespace.Ferrari"/>
  <MyType key="2" type="My.Namespace.Fiat"/>
</config>
```

Now you can read from that config and create your instances based on the type-info:

```
ICar CreateCar(int carType)
{
    foreach(var typeInfo in myConfig)
    {
        if(typeInfo.Key == carType) return Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(typeInfo.type));
    }
}
```

Now simply call `myFactory.CreateCare(2)` to get an instance of `Fiat`.

This surely assumes you have deserialized your config (e.g. using Linq2Xml or using `XmlSerializer`) and that the assembly containing the types has already been loaded at runtime. If this does not apply you should call `Assembly.Load` before.

Now all your factory still have to do is read the config-file, eventually load the assemblies and build a dictionary that caches the keys and the types to increase the performance a bit.

The advantage on relying on an external file is that you don´t have to re-ship your whole application but only those parts that actually *change*.

EDIT: Things may get complicated if your types don´t have a default-constructor and you have to provide args. However for the sake of simplicity we assume we *have* a default-constructor.

Comment: So you have moved the `switch` to the xml file. I can't imagine how happy will someone maintaining this code in 6 months be. Especially if you don't comment or document it **very** explicitly

Comment: @slawekwin You have to document in either case, this is not limited to this approach. Anyway see my last sentence on my answer.

Comment: My intent with this comment was to stress how important it is to comment such solutions thoroughly, so there is no confusion in the future. It might have come out too strong, sorry :)

Comment: What happens if your type doesn't have a default constructor?  You can't put that in the contract for your interface which makes this approach very brittle.

Comment: There is another issue with this and that is that putting the type reference into the config will easily break refactoring. This is a low risk area but can cause a runtime error when the class names and namespaces change. From experience you should never reference classes in this way unless they are separate versioned libraries that you know will never change.

Answer (score 0):

I think Vlad's suggestion in the comments is the better approach, which I made a bit more concrete in my follow up comment, but I'm elaborating below. Unlike [tym32167's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39488823/4594973), this approach does *not* couple your library to the specific app using it by means of the `type` parameter being sent into the `ICarFactory` types from the app itself.

In other words, I don't think tym32167's answer keeps your classes "closed for modification" every time you need to add a new implementation.

---

#### The Cars

```
public interface ICar {
    string Name { get; }
}

class BigCar : ICar {
    string Name {
        get { return "Big Car"; }
    }
}

class SmallCar : ICar {
    string Name {
        get { return "Small Car"; }
    }
}
```

#### The Factories

```
public interface ICarFactory {
    ICar CreateCar();
}

public class BigCarFactory : ICarFactory {
    ICar CreateCar() { return new BigCar (); }
}

public class SmallCarFactory : ICarFactory {
    ICar CreateCar() { return new SmallCar (); }
}
```

Notice they do not suffer from "control coupling", i.e. they don't rely on external 'magic' values to determine internal control flow of the factory. In other words, they're not `ICar CreateCar(int type);`, the factories are simply `ICar CreateCar();`. The factories should not be coupled to your specific application via the `type` parameter, which has app-specific meaning.

#### Putting them Together

Now in some arbitrary method in your client-side app where you have your car-creating logic, i.e. *outside* your library (e.g. reading your config file or something else), you can do something like:

```
public List<ICar> CreateCars() {
    // organize your factories based on whatever value you want for 'type'
    ICarFactory[] factories = { new BigCarFactory(), new SmallCarFactory() };
    List<ICar> carsList = new List<>();

    while (/* more config to read */ ) {
        int type = // read type from config, etc.
        carsList.Add(factories[type].CreateCar());
    }

    return carsList;
}
```

Now, every time you add a new `ICar` implementation, you create an associated `ICarFactory` implementation, which is obviously very easy to do, and you add a new factory to your `ICarFactory[] factories` array in whatever car `type` position you want for it and that `type` knowledge remains in your specific app, decoupled from your Car/Factory library.

---

Compared to other responses, why is my proposal **SOLID**?

1. **S:** These factories have 1 responsibility: create their car implementations; other proposals add the responsibility of figuring out what `type` means
2. **O:** Your `ICar` and `ICarFactory` can be extended by adding new implementations, but existing ones do not need to be modified when doing this.
3. **L:** We're already doing this b/c we're returning `ICar` objects, so it doesn't matter whether the implementation is a `BigCar` or `SmallCar` or whatever.
4. **I:** We're doing this here by keeping the interface and classes simple; other proposals couple your library to your app via the `type` parameter, which has app-specific meaning
5. **D:** In this particular case, the library classes don't exactly need to rely on external information being injected.

Comment: Regarding "2. O": You will have to modify the existing method `CreateCars()` for every new car type. So the OCP is still violated. And on a side-note: the D in SOLID stands for **D**pendency Inversion Principle, not for **D**esign-by-Contract.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, The `CreateCars` method is meant to be specific to the client-side app, not part of the car/car-factory library classes, which is what follows the OCP. Unlike other proposals, you don't have to modify the car/factory implementations just to allow creation of a new type of car; they just get extended.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, Good catch on the **D** part. I was obviously thinking about design-by-contract. Not sure why I did, but I've updated a few things including that. I also tried to make it more clear that the `CreateCars` method is meant to be on the client-side app, not inside the car/factory library side of things.

Comment: this is the same exact thing as @tym32167's answer, just without error checking and without class that "puts them together". I like his better, despite the fact that he wrote it in a bit unorganized way

Comment: @slawekwin I think the error-checking logic is out of scope for my post, since the question was not about how to perform error checking. I think we did similar things, but not exactly the same thing, though it might just be an issue of clarity. I got the impression that tym32167's response was coupling the library to the app, which is one thing I tried to address, based on how I understood that post.